# Powershell SQL Server stored procedure backup

Tags: sql-server, powershell, stored-procedures, backup

I am trying to backup one particular stored procedure from a SQL Server database by passing parameters from a Python program. Here is the code that I have tried but I keep getting an error.

```
param([string]$server='dbsed0898', [string]$dbname='global_hub',[string]$sp='dbo.gs_eligibility')

[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName(“Microsoft.SqlServer.SMO”) | out-null

$SMOserver = 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo' #-argumentlist $server
$srv = New-Object("$SMOserver.Server") $server
$db = $srv.databases[$dbname]

$Objects = $db.storedprocedures[$sp]
$scripter = new-object ("$SMOserver.Scripter") $srv

$Scripter.Script($Objects) | Out-File 
" C:\Users\fthoma15\Documents\backup_03212020.sql"

$db = $SMOserver.databases[$dbname]

$Objects = $db.storedprocedures[$sp]
$Scripter.Script($Objects) | Out-File
```

"C:\Users\fthoma15\Documents\backup_03212020.sql"

Error:

> Multiple ambiguous overloads found for "Script" and the argument count: "1".
>   At line:12 char:5
>   +     $Scripter.Script($Objects) | Out-File "C:\Users\fthoma15\Document ...
>   +     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>   + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException
>   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodCountCouldNotFindBest

Can someone help me?

Comment: I think you haven't declared `$Scripter` as an object. So you are getting the exception.

Comment: hi! @WasifHasan, Thanks for the response. I have changed the code as above but now i recieve a new error as pasted above.

Comment: Possibly you're using the `StoredProcedureCollection` incorrectly so it's returning a $null object. You either call `Item[String]` where string is a name without a schema or you call `Item[String, String]` where the first String is a name and the second String is a schema. (Seems backwards, I know.) REF: [StoredProcedureCollection.Item[String, String] Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.storedprocedurecollection.item)

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Thank you for guiding me in the right direction. posting the answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what i did.

```
param([string]$server='test', [string]$dbname='test',[string[]]$sp=('test','test'))

[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName(“Microsoft.SqlServer.SMO”) | out- 
null

$SMOserver = new-object ("Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Scripter") #-argumentlist 
$server
$srv = new-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server("$server")
$db = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Database
$db = $srv.Databases.Item("$dbname")
$Objects = $db.storedprocedures[$sp[1,3]]
$scripter = new-object ("$SMOserver") $srv

$Scripter.Script($Objects) | Out-File 
"C:\Users\fthoma15\Documents\backup_03212020.sql"
```

As suggested by AlwaysLearning, i changed the sp variable to an array list,splitting both schema and sp name.